# Why I can't upgrade my Mac Pro OS X 10.7 to a more recent version?

Tags: macos

Why I can't upgrade my Mac Pro OS X 10.7 to a more recent version?

My system specs are:

MacPro1,1 , Processor 2 x 3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon, Ram 6 GB 667 GHz ECC DDR2 FB-DIMM, Graphic Nvidia GeForce 8800 GT 512 MB, Serial Number C074200V08S

System Software: OS X Lion 10.7 (11A511)

Answer (score 2):

As indicated [here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-quad-3.0-specs.html), the last officially supported system software is Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Any later system (10.8-10.10) is not running on your Mac and you won't be able to upgrade.

[Here (english)](http://www.pro-tools-expert.com/home-page/2015/3/2/how-to-resurrect-a-2006-mac-pro-11-so-it-can-run-osx-yosemit.html) or [here (german)](http://www.apfeltalk.de/community/threads/installation-von-yosemite-auf-dem-macpro-1-1-und-2-1.469257/) you'll find a hack/workaround to get Yosemite running on your MacPro1,1, if it doesn't contain a 7300GT or X1900XT video card (which is true in your case because your Mac contains a GeForce 8800 GT).